# CSS equally distributed height and fill screen

Tags: css

Is it possible to make five CSS elements fill the entire screen (on top of each other), so that the height of the screen is equally distributed? Like in this sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRs0k.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link for the code that you have tried?

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam wtf.

Comment: @ErikMes i did't get his question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the height of `html` and `body` elements to `100%`, then set the height of each div to `20%`

```
html, body { height: 100% }
div { 
  height: 20%; 
  border: 1px #d2d2d2 solid; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

example JsBin: http://jsbin.com/owocog/1/edit

As alternative, on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) (even IE9) supporting the new `vh` viewport unit, you may simply write

```
div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20vh;  
}
```

example JsBin: http://jsbin.com/ufedat/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply create a container that fills the whole page, i.e. `height: 100%;` and add a height of 20% to each contained element.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/M3uqn/